# Xcode Crash when trying to drag NSCollectionView to storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nscollectionview

I am trying to add a **nscollectionview** to my **OSX project** but this will causes **Xcode** to force-close:

[image]

Every time when I am dragging the collectionview into the storyboard **Xcode** will be **force close**.

I do not know either I am the only one having this problem or everyone else has work around solution.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Nobody knows what Main Page Content Scene and Main Page Content are.

Comment: @halfer Noted. Thank you

Comment: @ElTomato Its just a blank NSviewcontroller with 2 custom view and i already set up the autolayout.
but thats not the case.
even when i add a new nsviewcontroller then add a nscollectionview. xcode will close directly. its not involve anything with my content.
i even try to create a new project and add a simple nscollectionview inside of nsviewcontroller (crash) inside nsviewcontroller with custom view(crash).

Comment: @ElTomato i need to know is this a xcode issue? is this common issue?
is there any solution to troubleshot what may have cause this.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen when targeting operating system verisons that don't support macOS 10.11+ UIKit-style `NSCollectionView`s.

I was able to get an "old-style" collection view into a storyboard by dragging one into a `xib` file, then opening it as XML text and copy-pasting the `<collectionView>` into the `<subviews>` of a parent view in the `storyboard` file.